# How to redirect with a bootstrap submit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I've been trying to append an action to my bootstrap submit button that looked like this:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Style(ButtonStyle.Primary).Text("Save").HtmlAttributes("@Url.Action('Action','Controller')")
```

But it won't work and I've tried to find a solution but found nothing...

so how do I create a submit button that submits a form and does directly redirect afterwords?

thank you for your answers :)

Comment: use ``return RedirectToAction`` in action to which form is submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect in your controller after the POST or GET method has finished everything else, like so:

```
    public ActionResult DeletePerson(int personId)
    {
        //do your deleting stuff here

        return RedirectToAction("Index"); //<-- send me to the index action method
    }
```

This will go to the Index action method which presumably will end up returning the Index view.

Comment: sorry I've found the misstake I made, I'm using bootstrap forms and i forgott to declare at the begin form line to define my action... but now I can perfectly use RedirectToAction. Thank you :)